# Trigger Test Class for Custom Setting not covered

Tags: unit-test

This is Trigger which i wrote but in test class only 48% is covered what i should do to increase code coverage.

```
trigger FundRequestRegionInsert on Fund_Request__c (before insert) {
    Auto_Number__c autNum = GeneralUtil.getAutoNumbers('ANZ');
    Auto_Number__c autNum1 = GeneralUtil.getAutoNumbers('INC');
    Auto_Number__c autNum2 = GeneralUtil.getAutoNumbers('ASN');
    Auto_Number__c autNum3 = GeneralUtil.getAutoNumbers('IND');
    Auto_Number__c autNum4 = GeneralUtil.getAutoNumbers('SAP');
    Integer i = 0;

    Map<Id,Account> ProgramMap;
    ProgramMap = new Map<Id,Account>([SELECT Id,Region__c FROM Account]);
    for(Fund_Request__c chrg : trigger.new){



        if(ProgramMap.get(chrg.Company_Name_New__c) != null && ProgramMap.get(chrg.Company_Name_New__c).Region__c == 'ANZ'){
            if(autNum.Value__c == Null) 
                autNum.Value__c = 0;
            chrg.Reference_Number__c = 'ANZ-'+ ++autNum.Value__c;  
            i++;  
        }                    
        if(ProgramMap.get(chrg.Company_Name_New__c) != null && ProgramMap.get(chrg.Company_Name_New__c).Region__c == 'INC'){           
            if(autNum1.Value__c == Null) 
                autNum1.Value__c = 0;
            chrg.Reference_Number__c = 'INC-'+ ++autNum1.Value__c;
            i++;  
        }
        if(ProgramMap.get(chrg.Company_Name_New__c) != null && ProgramMap.get(chrg.Company_Name_New__c).Region__c == 'ASN'){
            if(autNum2.Value__c == Null) 
                autNum2.Value__c = 0;
            chrg.Reference_Number__c = 'ASN-'+ ++autNum2.Value__c;
            i++;  
        } 
        if(ProgramMap.get(chrg.Company_Name_New__c) != null && ProgramMap.get(chrg.Company_Name_New__c).Region__c == 'IND'){
            if(autNum3.Value__c == Null) 
                autNum3.Value__c = 0;
            chrg.Reference_Number__c = 'IND-'+ ++autNum3.Value__c;
            i++;  
        } 
        if(ProgramMap.get(chrg.Company_Name_New__c) != null && ProgramMap.get(chrg.Company_Name_New__c).Region__c == 'SAP'){
            if(autNum4.Value__c == Null) 
                autNum4.Value__c = 0;
            chrg.Reference_Number__c = 'SAP-'+ ++autNum4.Value__c;
            i++;  
        }  


    }
    if(i != 0)
        update autNum;
    update autNum1;
    update autNum2;
    update autNum3;
    update autNum4;
}
```

Test class which i wrote...

```
@isTest
private class TestFundRequestInsertTrigger {

    static testMethod void myUnitTest() {
        // TO DO: implement unit test
        Account acc=new Account();
        acc.Name='test1';
        insert acc;


        Fund_Request__c fundreq= new Fund_Request__c();
        fundreq.Status__c='draft';
        fundreq.Activity_Name__c='test123';
        fundreq.Activity_Type__c='Colleteral&Advertising';
        fundreq.Target_Audience__c='Partners';
        fundreq.Objective_s__c='Partner Recruitment';
        fundreq.Objective_Others__c='Test123';
        fundreq.Start_Date__c=system.today().addDays(1);
        fundreq.End_Date__c=system.today().addDays(10);
        fundreq.Claim_Amount_USD__c=1000;
        fundreq.Total_Cost_USD__c=1000;
        fundreq.Company_Name_New__c=acc.Id;
        fundreq.Region__c='ANZ';
        fundreq.Reference_Number__c='ANZ' +1;
        insert fundreq;

        Auto_Number__c setting = new Auto_Number__c();
        setting.Name = 'ANZ';
        setting.Value__c = null;
        insert setting;




        Auto_Number__c autNum = new Auto_Number__c();
        autNum.Name = 'INC';
        autNum.Value__c = null;
        insert autNum;




    }
}
```

it is not covering 22 line no please help me to fix out this issue.

Comment: can you highlight the lines of code which are not covered?

Answer (score 3):

The way you code is written, you'd need to insert five of these account records; one for each of the five regions. This is how you'd fix the problem naively. However, I do not recommend moving this code to production, because you will run into errors.

## Unfiltered Query on Table

You're literally trying to query for every account in the database. This will result in either a 50k query row error (eventually), or a non-selective error if you have a large number of account records. Instead, you should be using the Aggregate-Query-Update pattern to get the correct accounts:

```
Map<Id, Account> accounts = new Map<Id, Account>();
for(Fund_Request__c record: Trigger.new) {
    accounts.put(record.Company_Name_New__c, null);
}
accounts.putAll([SELECT Region__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN :accounts.keySet()]);
for(Fund_Request__c record: Trigger.new) {
    // We'll do this in a moment
}
```

## Incorrect Code

You tried to put a DML guard using the variable `i`, but four of your five DML statements will always execute anyways, because the `if` statement only covers a single DML line. Also, you really should be using a collection (a list or map) to get the desired results (called bulkifying DML operations). Naively, you'd get better performance with:

```
upsert new Auto_Number__c[] { autNum, autNum1, autNum2, autNum3, autNum4 };
```

However, there happens to be an even better way, which we'll discuss later.

## Inefficient Code

Your code isn't DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself). You have variables that could be referenced using a simple collection, which both reduces the complexity of your code *and* your unit tests. Here, using maps can come in handy:

```
// Get all values at once, and clone the map to avoid errors.
Map<String, Auto_Number__c> autoNums = Auto_Number__c.getAll().deepClone(false);
for(Fund_Request__c record: Trigger.new) {
    Account company = accounts.get(record.Company_Name_New__c);
    if(company != null && company.Region__c != null) {
        Auto_Number__c autoNum = autoNums.get(company.Region__c);
        if(autoNum == null || autoNum.Value__c == null) {
            // Create a new record
            // Assignment as a parameter both assigns the value and places it in the map)
            autoNums.put(company.Region__c, autoNum = new Auto_Number__c(Name__c=company.Region__c, Value__c=0));
        }
        record.Reference_Number__c = company.Region__c+'-'+ (++autoNum.Value__c);
    }
 }
 upsert autoNums.values() Auto_Number__c.Name;
```

As you can see, it supports all five regions *and* any future regions you might load in the future, all without any extra coding later. Also see how there's now just a single DML operation, no matter how many regions are involved. This code is rather highly optimized.

Putting this all together, your code should look more like this:

```
trigger FundRequestRegionInsert on Fund_Request__c (before insert) {
    Map<Id, Account> accounts = new Map<Id, Account>();
    for(Fund_Request__c record: Trigger.new) {
        accounts.put(record.Company_Name_New__c, null);
    }
    accounts.putAll([SELECT Region__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN :accounts.keySet()]);
    Map<String, Auto_Number__c> autoNums = Auto_Number__c.getAll().deepClone(false);
    for(Fund_Request__c record: Trigger.new) {
        Account company = accounts.get(record.Company_Name_New__c);
        if(company != null && company.Region__c != null) {
            Auto_Number__c autoNum = autoNums.get(company.Region__c);
            if(autoNum == null || autoNum.Value__c == null) {
                // Create a new record
                // Assignment as a parameter both assigns the value and places it in the map)
                autoNums.put(company.Region__c, autoNum = new Auto_Number__c(Name__c=company.Region__c, Value__c=0));
            }
            record.Reference_Number__c = company.Region__c+'-'+ (++autoNum.Value__c);
        }
    }
    upsert autoNums.values() Auto_Number__c.Name;
}
```

## Unit Testing

As far as your unit test goes, you need to insert a new record, then verify the value is correct. Something like this:

```
@isTest static void myUnitTest() {
    Account company = new Account(Name='Test', Region__c='IND');
    insert company;
    Fund_Request__c req = new Fund_Request__c(Company_Name_New__c=company.Id);
    insert req;
    // Query back to validate trigger logic
    req = [SELECT Reference_Number__c FROM Fund_Request__c];
    System.assertEquals('IND-1', req.Reference_Number__c);
}
```

Comment: i am not able to call general utility class in test class so that these all lines of code is not covered.

Comment: i am also tried in your way but that's not working by inserting five test record with different condition. can you please help me.

Comment: @NehaPandey You'll want to review my answer now that I'm more or less done with it. You will need to populate additional fields as necessary.

Comment: Brian, this is an incredible act of generosity and patience on your behalf. What a great answer. I had to mention it here. Not many people would take the time you took to give such a comprehensive answer for a seemingly simple,e question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as @sfdcfox suggest you need to insert five records one for each condition. 
Also insert five `Auto_Number__c`  records and in your trigger check if you don't found any `Auto_Number__c` record otherwise you will get null pointer exception. Beside that you also need to follow some best practices so that your code will work smoothly in the production.

For example in place of 5 DML use List and insert record in one shot. You can use condition for to check whether you need to insert record or need. follow same thing in your test class.

Here is some reference for your help.

1. [Apex Code Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices)
2. [Trigger Frameworks and Apex Trigger Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices)